# Getting Post validation failed: postedby: Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path "postedby"

Tags: mongoose, jwt

I am getting this error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value` while trying to insert a post in express Nodejs. This `postedby:req.id` is causing the problem. I tried changing to type `String` in the `Post` model for `postedby` field and I got the error that says Cast to String failed and here are the Model, Routes and JWT code:

```js
     //Post Model
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const {ObjectID} = mongoose.Schema.Types;
    
    const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title:{
            type: String,
            required: "Title is required",
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength:250
            },
        postedby:{
            type:ObjectID,ref:"user"
        },
        date: {
            type:Date,
            default: Date.now 
        },    
    },
    { timestamps: true });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

```js
    //JWT
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    
    function JWTAuthenticatToken(req, res, next) {
        const {authorization} = req.headers  
        
        if(!authorization){
         return res.sendStatus(401).json({error:"You have to be logged in!"})
        }
        const token = authorization.replace('Bearer ','')
        jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET,(err,userData) =>{
         if(err) return res.sendStatus(401).json({error:"You have to be logged in!"})
            req.id = userData
            next()    
     
         }) 
     }
    
    module.exports = JWTAuthenticatToken
```

```js
    //Post Routes
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const Post = require('../models/post');
    const JWTAuthenticatToken = require('../middleware/JWTAuthentication');
    
    router.post('/post',JWTAuthenticatToken, async (req, res) => {   
        const{title,body} = req.body   
        console.log(req.id)
                const post = new Post({
                title: title,
                body:body,
                postedby:req.id})            
                const postresult = await post.save()
                res.json({post:postresult})
                });
```

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciated for all the help. Thanks again

Comment: Does `console.log(req._id)`  provides a valid objectId

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks

Comment: I made made typo error in the above code. It should be console.log(req.id) instead of console.log(req._id). thanks